# JQuery doesn't work in partial view i can't fix

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

When i click button jquery doesn't work in partial view

here is code

Controller

```
public PartialViewResult Chat()
    return PartialView();
}
```

Button

```
<input id="button" type="submit">
```

Render In HTML

```
<div id="test">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("Chat");}
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#button').live('click', function () {
     $('#test').load('@Url.Action("Chat")');
});
```

Comment: `live()` was deprecated and removed from jQuery several years ago. You should update the version of jQuery you're using and use the delegated signature of `on()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Several possible reasons most likely including:

1. you didn't include jQuery library at all
2. you didn't call `$('#button').live()` in a `$(document).ready()` statement

Comment: .live() is deprecated, use .on() instead

Answer (score 0):

jQuery initialisation is done to all matching elements in the document at the time of running. If you are dynamically loading your partial view after the initialisation, new elements matching the filter will not be automatically initialised. You will need to run the jQuery initialisers again after the .load is complete.

This will also double up existing matching elements' events so you need to run them using the container div to restrict the elements that will be affected.

```
$('#test').find('xxxxx').click(function.....
```